# Regex: Get text level 1 by using notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a lot text like this:

```
internet-2014/654765/dd
learn-english-and-indonesian/7653457/dd
Nutrition-Healthy-100%/103767767/dd
```

I want to remove everything except:

```
internet-2014
learn-english-and-indonesian
Nutrition-Healthy-100%
```

Can you show me the regex, please ? Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex and then replace the matched characters with an empty string.

```
\/.*
```

- `\/` Matches the first literal `/` symbol.
- `.*` Greedy Match of any character zero or more times. So this regex would match the first `/` symbol and onwards, it greedily matches all the characters upto the line end.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mD8iB4/3)

Comment: It *is* greedy. It is not non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

Replace everything after and including a slash with blank:

```
Search: /.*
Replace: <nothing>
```

Note that it is not necessary to escape the forward slash, as it has no special meaning in regex.

Comment: @avin there's no difference. Some languages, like JavaScript, allow delimiting regex with slashes, but not notepad. I much prefer code that is as small as it can be (but still understandable).